# Comparar Data Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

Tenho a seguinte coluna em oracle

```
DATA_FILTRO
01/04/2017 10:27:15
```

Gostaria de fazer a comparação do mês e ano:

```
SELECT DATA_FILTRO
 FROM TABELA
WHERE TO_CHAR(DATA_FILTRO,'MM/YYYY') ='04/2017'
```

No PLSQL funciona, porém no PHP dá erro

```
oci_execute(): ORA-01843: not a valid month in
```

Código PHP

```
public function metodo($data){
    $conn = new ConnectionFactory();
    $con = $conn->getConnection();
    $query = "SELECT DATA_FILTRO
                FROM TABELA
               WHERE TO_CHAR(DATA_FILTRO,'MM/YYYY') ='04/2017'";
    $stmt = ociparse($con, $query);

    oci_execute($stmt);
     while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_ASSOC)){
        echo $row['DATA_FILTRO'];
     }
    $conn->closeConnection($con);
    return $protocoloList;
  }catch ( PDOException $ex ){  echo "Erro: ".$ex->getMessage(); }
}
```

No PHP Só funciona se for o mês **05/2017**

Comment: $query = "SELECT DATA_FILTRO
                FROM TABELA
               WHERE TRUNC(DATA_FILTRO,'MM') = TO_DATE('01/'|| '04/2017','DD/MM/YYYY')"; Poderia testar assim?

Comment: continua o erro

Comment: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/447692-data-oracle-x-php/  não conheço php mas creio que o problema na diferença do formato da session do banco contra a da aplicação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ORACLE não recomenda você converter um campo para realizar uma consulta, pois, se a coluna data_filtro possuir um índice, ao converter a coluna o banco não irá utilizar o plano de execução como o índice, onerando o tempo de execução de sua query.
Outro ponto, é que a ORACLE recomenda utilizar bind variable para realização de consultas dinâmicas, pois, ao montar uma string com o valor da data (sem o bind) o ORACLE não irá utilizar as estatísticas e irá criar um novo plano de execução, também onerando a sua query.

Sem bind:

```
$query = "SELECT DATA_FILTRO
            FROM TABELA
           WHERE DATA_FILTRO = TO_DATE('01/04/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY')";
```

Com Bind:

```
$query = "SELECT DATA_FILTRO
                FROM TABELA
               WHERE DATA_FILTRO = to_date(':data01', 'dd/mm/yyyy'";
$valor_data = '01/04/2017';
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":data01", $valor_data);
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.oci-bind-by-name.php